# PureComponent in react is not doing shallow comparison

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the Below class component, the `componentDidUpdate` method is getting executed every time I click on the button.

If we go by the logic of shallow comparison in https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/blob/main/packages/fbjs/src/core/shallowEqual.js, there are 2 states which can cause re-render

1. `count` which is a primitive type and is `0` even after setState
2. `obj` which is an object, but first level `key1` has primitive value which is again `0` both the times. So, that should also not cause re-render. Then why does my component re-render every time I click on the button ?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
class App extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      obj: {
        key1: 0,
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('App: component updated');
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    const tempObj =  {
      key1: 0,
    };
    this.setState({
      count: 0,
      obj: tempObj,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='top-button'>
        <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>`Default: ${this.state.count}`</button>;
        </div>
        <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```